# How do I fit a single data set into my svm?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm very new to using scikit-learn.  I'm looking to fit new data into an existing GridSearchCV.  This is where I created my object.

```
svm = GridSearchCV(SVC(C=1, probability=True), param_grid, cv=5).fit(x, y)
```

So I create the GridSearchCV object and I call fit with my entire data set.  Later I add more data to the data set.  My data set is fairly large, so it takes about 30 seconds to recreate this object each time.  Is there a faster way to just add the additional data, instead of re-fitting the entire dataset?  Again, I'm pretty new to this, so sorry if the answer is obvious.

Comment: I don't _think_ you'll be able to get away with not refitting the SVC every time you add more data-- I'm pretty sure SVC training requires the whole dataset. However, it does look like the GridSearchCV object has a [refit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) function that you might look into so you don't have to create an entirely new object.

Comment: Can't fit twice, resets the data, my bad. Have a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html 3rd bullet point

Comment: Please also have a look at scikit's SGDClassifier. You can use loss='hinge' in order to have an SVM. Then, use the 'warm_start' option!